# Force nginx to return 404 for missing assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

We are using Nginx with our Rails application. We see requests in the Rails log file that looking for assets which are not there anymore, like this:

```
Aug  8 09:18:06 www rails-prod ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] 
"/assets/application-cd8df963daec0c7c81c70254f7549eb028980b5a39df2c2c16fd4e6f9794c4b4.css"):
```

The hash in the url changes every time we change the css, so it is correct that this asset does not exist anymore.

The Rails server does not answer asset requests, since all the assets are precompiled. How can we force Nginx to return 404 error?

This is the Nginx configuration file:

```
upstream my_app {
  server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /assets {
    alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location /public {
    alias /var/app/current/public;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}
```

Tried to add `break;` to the `location /assets` group, but it didn't help. Also tried to change the `alias` to `root`, but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `try_files`? It'd go something like this (there are other usages of this that you can find and use to solve your particular problem):

```
  location /assets {
    try_files $uri @missing
  }

  location @missing {
    return 404;
  }
```

Nginx will try and serve the request, but if it turns out that the files are missing, it'll return a 404.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out I was looking at the wrong config file. Nginx responds with 404 if the file is missing using the above config I pasted in. But also tried your setting and it also works.